Error " Unknown CMake command > "pluginlib_export_plugin_description_file". "
I keep getting this error when I enter catkin_make:

CMake Error at my_package/CMakeLists.txt:48
(pluginlib_export_plugin_description_file):   Unknown CMake command
"pluginlib_export_plugin_description_file".

The line in the CMakeLists.txt is the following:

pluginlib_export_plugin_description_file(controller_interface
config/pd_gravity_compensation_controller.xml)

Unfortunately, also by searching online, I could not find any useful insight.
What could I do?

It would be a good idea to look at a current plugin as an example of what works. The relevant portion of this CMakeLists.txt is:
install(FILES blp_plugin.xml
    DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_SHARE_DESTINATION}
)

